# How do I get all the child tag names of an XML document using c#?

Tags: c#, xml, performance, tags

I am trying to find an efficient way to parse xml data into an SQL table.

This is a small example of the XML I will get, in reality there will be around 20-25 tags inside the property tag and hundreds of entries.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<entry m:etag="W/&quot;28&quot;">
<id>114</id>
<title type="text">Title 1</title>
<updated>2012-07-09T15:02:08+01:00</updated>
<author>
  <name />
</author>
<m:properties>
  <d:ContentTypeID>456</d:ContentTypeID>
  <d:ApproverComments>Correction to Title</d:ApproverComments>
  <d:Name>bar.pdf</d:Name>
  <d:Title>Title</d:Title>
  <d:DocumentOwnerId m:type="Edm.Int32">20</d:DocumentOwnerId>
  <d:DocumentControllerId m:type="Edm.Int32" m:null="true"></d:DocumentControllerId>
</m:properties>
</entry>
<entry m:etag="W/&quot;28&quot;">
<id>115</id>
<title type="text">Title 2</title>
<updated>2012-07-09T15:05:35+01:00</updated>
<author>
  <name />
</author>
<m:properties>
  <d:ContentTypeID>456</d:ContentTypeID>
  <d:ApproverComments>Correction of Title2</d:ApproverComments>
  <d:Name>foo.pdf</d:Name>
  <d:Title>Title 2</d:Title>
  <d:DocumentOwnerId m:type="Edm.Int32">20</d:DocumentOwnerId>      
</m:properties>
</entry>
```

I will need to look at each 'entry' and pull out all the tag names inside the m: properties tag and set those as the columns for the SQL table.

I'm looking for a more efficient way to do this, rather than having to iterate through all entries' property tags then putting together a list of tag names that I then need to cross reference to make sure I get them all.

I have been trying to find a function along the lines of;

```
String TagNames = XMLDoc.getChildNode('properties').getChildNodeNames()
```

TagNames would equal "ContentTypeID, ApproverComments, Name, Title, DocumentOwnerID, DocumentControllerID"

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making the assumption you already have an `XDocument`, we'll name it `doc`, one approach might be this:

```
doc.GetElements("entry")
   .Select(e => e.GetElement("m:properties")
                 .GetElements()
                 .Select(ce => ce.Name.LocalName)
                 .ToList())
   .ToList();
```

That should give you a `List<List<string>>` for each entry.

You could even qualify the inner list with the `id` of the `entry`:

```
doc.GetElements("entry")
   .Select(e =>
   {
       var id = e.GetElement("id").Value;

       e.GetElement("m:properties")
        .GetElements()
        .Select(ce => string.Format("{0}|{1}", id, ce.Name.LocalName))
        .ToList()
    })
   .ToList();
```

Comment: +1 That's great had to make a couple of changes to make it work fully with the data but otherwise great :)

Comment: @Funkotron_King, I'm glad I could be of assistance!